# possible ways to insert multiple values of the same field

Tags: apex, visualforce, json

I have an Object with RecordNum, RecordVal, And User__id as a reference .. and a VF page as the following

```
<apex:pageBlock> 
   <apex:inputField value="{!Object.RecordVal}" label="val 1:" /> 
   <apex:inputField value="{!Object.RecordVal}" label="val 2:" /> 
   <apex:inputField value="{!Object.RecordVal}" label="val 3:" /> 
   <apex:inputField value="{!Object.RecordVal}" label="val 4:" /> 
   <apex:inputField value="{!Object.RecordVal}" label="val 5:" /> 
   ... 
    <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!saveObject}" /> 
</apex:pageBlock>
```

what are the possible or the best way to insert this records ? And how can I do this using JSON ?

Comment: You want to insert multiple records with different values in the RecordVal field for each record ?

Comment: no , for example recordNum = 1 , Record Val = 1
recordNum = 2 , Record Val = 2 .. can I use Json to insert 1,2,3.. in recordNum and val1,val2,val3.. in recordVal ?

Comment: The only way to store multiple values in a single field is to make the field have a text datatype and then have some sort of separator between the values (e.g. for multi-select picklists a semi-colon). Are you saying you want to store JSON in the fields?

Comment: how to do that in JSON, get the values in the controller if i have more than 20 inputField (recordVal) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation using a simple Apex class to hold the label/value and then only serializing the values to the JSON field:

```
public with sharing class MyController {
    public class Record {
        public String label {get; set;}
        public String value {get; set;}
        public Record(String label, String value) {
            this.label = label;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
    public Record[] records {
        get {
            if (records == null) {
                records = new Record[] {};
                for (Integer i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                    records.add(new Record('val ' + i + ':', ''));
                }
            }
            return records;
        }
        set;
    }
    public PageReference save() {
        ...
        String[] values = new String[] {};
        for (Record r : records) {
            values.add(r.value);
        }
        // Store JSON array of values
        object.RecordVal__c = JSON.serializePretty(values);
        ...
    }
}
```

The page would look something like this:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:repeat value="{!records}" var="r">
        <apex:inputText label="{!r.label}" value="{!r.value}"/> 
    <apex:repeat>
    <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}" /> 
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: what if I need to repeat these inputs in two places (pageBlock) with different numbers but in the same form (same save button) ?

Comment: Then have a `records1` and a `records2` property (or better give them more descriptive names) and have two copies of the `pageBlock` (or you could create an `apex:component` to avoid duplicating the markup).

Comment: Error: testController Compile Error: unexpected token: 'Record' at line 6 column 9

Comment: @user3003810 I'd missed "class" out from the second line above - I've added it now. I didn't compile the code I posted - there may be other compilation errors.

Comment: @keigh-c  Error: Could not resolve the entity from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!r.value}'. <apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

Comment: @user3003810 Change apex:inputField to apex:inputText.